# Unable to extract data using Scrapy with class name containing trailing spaces

Tags: python, html, css, scrapy

I'm trying to use scrapy to extract data from Steam about users' top 10 played games ordered by play time. However, I am unable to output the name of each of the games because the css classes containing the name text have trailing spaces.

I'm new to both Python and the Scrapy library, so apologies for any mistakes/poor formatting.

The class and python code are as follows:

## Exact class code

```
<div class="gameListRowItemName ellipsis ">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive</div> == $0
```

## Scrapy parser code

```
def parse(self, response):

some other code...

return {
    some other code... 
    'gamename': response.css("div.gameListRowItemName.ellipsis ::text").extract()
        
    }
```

I have made sure to include the ".ellipsis" to account for this being a multi-class css definition, however I can't find what a trailing space in the css class means.

I've attempted using multiple different variations on "div.gameListRowItemName.ellipsis ::text" to try and access this text (such as ".gameListRowItemName ::text"), but the spider only ever returns a blank list.

I don't think there is an issue anywhere else in the spider affecting my output, as the spider also returns the username which works correctly.

Does anyone know how I can work around this issue?

Comment: Did you try this? response.css("div.gameListRowItemName::text")?

Comment: I can tell from that `== $0` that you have copied the HTML from your web browser DOM representation. Please, make sure that the actual underlying HTML code contains the same HTML code. It’s possible the text comes from JavaScript. See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Comment: You were right, the area I was trying to scrape was in a <script> section! Thank you for pointing me towards the scrapy documentation for how to deal with it, I should be able to have a go at that tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **css selector** you can simply pass the first class name.

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
response = Selector(text='<div class="gameListRowItemName ellipsis ">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive</div> == $0')
# with css selectors
print('Css:',response.css("div.gameListRowItemName::text").extract())

# with xpath selectors
print('Xpath:',response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"gameListRowItemName")]/text()').extract())
```

Output

```
Css: ['Counter-Strike: Global Offensive']
Xpath: ['Counter-Strike: Global Offensive']
```

Learn about [css](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and xpath selectors [xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) on w3schools.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've just tried using "div.gameListRowItemName::text" in my css selector, but I'm still only getting a blank list in my output (despite running your test code to prove to myself that it should work). Is there something else that could be the issue? As I said in the question, I know the spider accesses the website correctly as it does output the correct username, so I can't see what's wrong.

Comment: Can you share your spider code? or the whole response text.

Comment: The spider code is only this at the moment:

`import scrapy

class UserSpider(scrapy.Spider):#CrawlSpider):

    name = 'users'

    start_urls = ['https://steamcommunity.com/id/Joe_Blogs/games/?tab=all']
    
    def parse(self, response):
    yield {
            'username': response.css('.whiteLink ::text').extract_first(),
            'gamename': response.css('.gameListRowItemName ::text').extract_first()
        }`

and then the website is [example steam profile](https://steamcommunity.com/id/Joe_Blogs/games/?tab=all) where I'm after the text about each game listed.

Comment: A pastebin link to the spider code for clarity, as I didn't realise comments don't have line breaks: https://pastebin.com/cqgYLcTS

Comment: ok so you need to check the page source. I see that you were only  inspecting the dom with Dev Tool.If you see page source(view-source:https://steamcommunity.com/id/Joe_Blogs/games/?tab=all) you will see the data is loaded in js.
I would suggest you to read the data in json and parse.

Comment: Okay brilliant, thank you for the help! I'll do my best to have a go at that tomorrow and hopefully get it working.